# indexOf.call vs array.indexOf in jQuery's source

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was browsing the source of [jQuery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L680) and bumped into this:

```
return indexOf.call( array, elem );
```

*- [Line 683](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L683)*

I was wondering what was the logic behind that, and why not do:

```
return array.indexOf(elem );
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess is the author of that code just does not want to care what target is passed into `.inArray()`.

If for instance, one would call `$.inArray( 42, 'hello' )` would obviously crash if we would call `.indexOf()` on the passed variable. The `Number.prototype` does (along with other types) not know about such a method.

By applying the `Array.prototype.indexOf` method on the passed variable, the `.indexOf()` method will take care of us.